# Is there an arithmetic function $\alpha(n)$ such that $\mu(n)=(\alpha*1)(n)$?

Tags: mobius-function

I've been looking into finding an arithmetic function $\alpha(n)$ for which its Dirichlet Convolution with the constant function $1$ is the Mobius Function, i.e.$$(\alpha(n)*1)=\mu(n)$$
I do not know if such a function exists, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) we can read that $1 *\mu=\varepsilon$ which is the identity of the Dirichlet convolution operation $*$. The identity of this operation, $\varepsilon$ is zero for all values in its domain except $1$ where $\varepsilon(1)=1$. So then multiplying by $\mu$ we have $1*\mu*\mu=\epsilon*\mu =\mu$. Then we should ask ourselves what is $\mu*\mu$? and the answer to this question is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2204217/dirichlet-convolution-of-the-mobius-function-with-itself?rq=1).